# How to encrypt an image while being able to show it?

Tags: php, image, encryption

I'm researching about image encryption in PHP. How would I go about encrypting the image while still being able to view the image (I'm expecting totally different colours or distortion, depending on the encryption method used).

My method now was to encrypt the entire binary data of the image file, but I think my problem is that the header of the image file is lost.

How could i change just the body (data) of the image without losing the header and other stuff?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

> How would I go about encrypting the image while still being able to view the image (I'm expecting totally different colours or distortion, depending on the encryption method used).

It sounds like you want to go through the ritual that Filippo Valsorda used to make [ECB Penguin pop art](https://blog.filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin/):

> ### My take at it
>
> First thing needed was an image format where the pixels were represented sequentially as plain bytes, without any compression, and possibly with a simple header. The perfect candidate turned out to be the [PPM binary format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format#PPM_example), part of the Netpbm spec. (It is just basically a ASCII header and then a sequence of 3-bytes RGB representations of the pixels.)
>
> Here is the process:
>
> ```
> # First convert the Tux to PPM with Gimp
> # Then take the header apart
> head -n 4 Tux.ppm > header.txt
> tail -n +5 Tux.ppm > body.bin
> # Then encrypt with ECB (experiment with some different keys)
> openssl enc -aes-128-ecb -nosalt -pass pass:"ANNA" -in body.bin -out body.ecb.bin
> # And finally put the result together and convert to some better format with Gimp
> cat header.txt body.ecb.bin > Tux.ecb.ppm
> ```
>
> And the result! Click for the original. It makes for a great nerdy office decoration, much like "Crypto Safety Procedures"!

Of course, if you were expecting to be able to display an unaltered image while still encrypting it, that's simply not possible.